# Using WebForms via C# how do I initialize/create variables that are used throughout my application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, include, global-variables

I'm still working on my transition from traditional .asp to ASP.NET (C# Webforms). In traditional .asp I could create config.asp. Within this file, I could initialize certain variables. For example if I wanted to set a file path for uploading, downloading, etc. I could say

```
Dim myNameIs = "Bufford T. Jones"
```

Then, as long as I included the config.asp file anywhere in my app I could simply say

```
Response.Write myNameIs;
```

How do I accomplish something similar in C# Webforms? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, C# doesn't have the concept of global variables like VB.net does.  In a case like this you can use session state to store information that would be available throughout the application like so:

```
Session["UserName"] = "Bufford T. Jones";
```

And then to read it:

```
string theUsersNameIs = (string)Session["UserName"];
```

Comment: as far as i remember, session["fieldName"] is of the type Object. Maybe a cast during getting the field? :)

Comment: Gary, I appreciate your answer. I'd forgotten all about session variables. Throughout my programming career I've avoided using them. Don't they take away from your memory? I only need to use 3 or 4 of them though so maybe that would work . For example an upload file directory name etc. What's the group consensus?

Comment: @Gregbert If your only storing normal data in session, small strings etc, it isn't a problem, thats what its there for.

Comment: @Gary-Stewart Thanks much, I'll be using your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton service for manage your global properties(variables), But if you are not able to work with dependency injection, you can use static class instead of singleton service.

```
public static class Current
{
    public static string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Now you could set and get Username in throughout of your application.